# Adding Stripe to a Python Project

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, stripe-payments

How can I add Stripe libraries to a Python google app engine project? I've read something about pip and easy_install but I couldn't understand how to implement them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Simply manually add the Stripe Python library to your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a virtual environment run this command:

```
python3.6 -m pip install stripe
```

where 3.6 can be replaced with the python version you are using for your project. The pythonx.x -m pip installs stripe for the particular python version you are on and doesn't affect other python installations. If you want to install stripe for all versions of python, just do pip install stripe.

If you are using a virtual environment then once it the environment run, pip install stripe.